# how to give default values in protocol buffer?

Tags: protocol-buffers

```
message Person {
  required Empid = 1 [default = 100];
  required string name = 2 [default = "Raju"];
  optional string occupation = 3;
  repeated string snippets = 4;
}
```

Can I give the default values as mentioned above?

Comment: I think you missed a `;` on end of the `Empid` field :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: The below answer is for proto2 only, proto3 doesn't allow custom default values.

Yes, you can give default values as you had written. `default` is optional for `required`, but for `optional` you have to mention the `default` values else type specific value is automatically assigned. Moreover you forgot to mention the type for `Empid`.

protobuf language guide states that

> If the default value is not specified for an `optional` element, a
> type-specific default value is used instead: for `strings`, the default
> value is the *empty string*. For `bool`s, the default value is *false*. For
> numeric types, the default value is *zero*. For `enums`, the default value
> is the *first value listed in the enum's type definition*. This means
> care must be taken when adding a value to the beginning of an enum
> value list.

Comment: To clarify, I can not seem to set a different default value for strings.  So is that still not possible.  They are always just defaulted to empty string?

Answer (score 32):

For `proto3`, custom default values are disallowed.

Comment: If I want custom default values, what should I do?

Comment: @ch271828n, one option could be to use proto2. Another _might_ be to write custom add-ons.

Comment: can somebody link to the rationale for why it was removed? for the above string field `name`, I believe you can differentiate between an explicitly set empty-string and a defaulted empty-string with the (java/grpc --presumably similar on other platforms) `hasName()` method. Is this the suggested work-around?